# Flask Upload Image to S3 without saving it to local file system

Tags: flask, boto3

I need to upload a a user submitted photo to an s3 bucket. However I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage
```

How am I able to store the file as string/bytes instead of FileStorage? The relevent code is as follows:

```
@user_api.route('upload-profile-photo', methods=['PUT'])
@Auth.auth_required
def upload_profile_photo():
  """
  Upload User Profile Photo
  """
  key = Auth.auth_user()
  bucket = 'profile-photos'
  content_type = request.mimetype
  image_file = request.files['file']
  client = boto3.client('s3',
                        region_name='sfo2',
                        endpoint_url='https://example.xxx.amazonaws.com',
                        aws_access_key_id=os.environ['ACCESS_KEY'],
                        aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['SECRET_KEY'])
  with open(image_file, "rb") as f:
    client.upload_fileobj(
        bucket,
        f,
        key,
        ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read', 'ContentType': content_type}
    )

  return custom_response({'message': 'image uploaded'}, 200)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

iTo achieve that with a `FileStorage`, I use the method `put_object()`:

```
from werkzeug import secure_filename

@user_api.route('upload-profile-photo', methods=['PUT'])
@Auth.auth_required
def upload_profile_photo():
    """
    Upload User Profile Photo
    """
    key = Auth.auth_user()
    bucket = 'profile-photos'
    content_type = request.mimetype
    image_file = request.files['file']

    client = boto3.client('s3',
                          region_name='sfo2',
                          endpoint_url='https://example.xxx.amazonaws.com',
                          aws_access_key_id=os.environ['ACCESS_KEY'],
                          aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['SECRET_KEY'])

    filename = secure_filename(image_file.filename)  # This is convenient to validate your filename, otherwise just use file.filename

    client.put_object(Body=image_file,
                      Bucket=bucket,
                      Key=filename,
                      ContentType=content_type)

    return custom_response({'message': 'image uploaded'}, 200)
```

Note the call to [`secure_filename()`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.14.x/utils/#werkzeug.utils.secure_filename) is optional (you can simply pass `image_file.filename`), but can be very handy to validate the filename.
 Otherwise it would be nice to add some exception handlings, but the rough idea is here: no need to `open()` the file (that would need to be stored locally).

I encourage to have a look at [the documentation here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object), to understand the difference with `upload_fileobj()`

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the functions put.object and upload_fileobj. Your suggestion worked. Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to say `secure_filename(image_file.filename)` ?  I don't see where a `file` variable is created.

Answer (score 0):

```
  import boto3   
  s3 = boto3.client(
            "s3",
            aws_access_key_id= "*************",
            aws_secret_access_key="**********"
        ) 

  @login_blueprint.route('/uploadfile', methods=['POST'])
         file= request.files['file']
        
         try:
                    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                    acl="public-read"
                    s3.upload_fileobj(
                        file,
                        'bucket-name',
                        file.filename,
                        ExtraArgs={
                            "ACL": acl,
                            "ContentType":  file.content_type
                        }
                    )
        
         except Exception as e:
                    resp = jsonify(e)
                    resp.status_code =200
                    return resp
```