# Upload data to S3 bucket without saving it to a disk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, io, boto3

Ther is the `boto3` method `upload_file(Filename='path')` that uses the `Filename` parameter to read a file from a disk and upload it to a bucket. Is it possible to upload data without saving it to a disk?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask Upload Image to S3 without saving it to local file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55292986/flask-upload-image-to-s3-without-saving-it-to-local-file-system)

Comment: @janpeterka Yes, but this is a special case for Flask.

Comment: The important part, using `put_object()` instead of `upload_file()` is the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save text file:

```
obj = 'some string'
bucket = 'my-bucket'
key = 'prefix/filename.txt'

boto3.client('s3').put_object(Body=obj, Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
```

Save csv file from pandas dataframe:

```
df = my-dataframe
bucket = 'my-bucket'
key = 'prefix/filename.csv'

csv_buffer = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
boto3.client('s3').put_object(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue(), Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
```

Answer (score 0):

S3 connection with credential

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import io

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', endpoint_url='',
  aws_access_key_id = '',
  aws_secret_access_key = '')
```

Create dataframes and upload

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': ['a', 'b', 'c']})

csv_buffer = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
s3.Bucket('BUCKET_NAME').put_object(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue(),  Key='df.csv')
```